# adding Progress Bar to my dataCall function - Android

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

How do I add a Progress Bar when a user selects a spinner item that triggers a http request. Do I add it to the class doing the http request (dataCall) or the main activity that has the spinner in it?

I have a class `DataCall` that when called does a http call to a php script that gets data from a MySQL database and returns data in a JSON format. This class is called after a spinner item is selected. The data returned is added to another spinner in the same activity. I am trying to show the progress wheel when the class `DataCall`  is doing its thing.  Below is my code for calling `DataCall`  from my `MainActivity` and the code from `DataCall` .

**MainActivity that calls DataCall (See below) when the spinner is selected. When DataCall returns data it updates another spinner with the new data.**

```
statespinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) 
     {
      int id = parent.getId();

      if (spinner1_count2 < spinner1_count1 ) {
          spinner1_count2++;  } 
         else 
         {
             city.clear();
             String item = statespinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
             String spinnerContentType = "city";
             String spinnerURL = "getStoreCity.php?state=" + item;


//CALLING DATACALL BELOW
                 String city_data =  DataCall.getJSON(spinnerURL,spinnerContentType);
             Log.d(TAG, city_data);
             String state_spinner_log = "STATE SPINNER";
             Log.d(TAG, state_spinner_log);

             JSONArray jsonArray;    
             try {

                 cityjsonArray = new JSONArray(city_data);


                 for (int i=0; i<cityjsonArray.length(); i++)
                 {   
                     String styleValue2 = cityjsonArray.getJSONArray(i).getString(0);    
                     Log.d(TAG, styleValue2);
                     city.add(styleValue2);
                     adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

                 }
                //

                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }




          }

     }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

**DataCall Class:**

```
 public class DataCall extends Activity {
        private static final String TAG = "MyApp";


         public static String getJSON(String myUrlString, String contentType){  

                    String line = null;
                    String tag_value = null;
                    try {

                        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://www.mywebsite.com/getdata/" + myUrlString);

                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                        line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server1</msg></results>";
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server2</msg></results>";
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server3</msg></results>";
                    }catch (Exception anything) {
                        //Whatever

                    }

                    return line;

            }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to have to move this web call out to a different thread as it will take an unknown amount of time to run and may cause an ANR.

If you use ASyncTask it has an inbuilt mechanism for updating a progress bar as the background thread runs. There is a lot of valuable information at this link

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Hope this helps, m

Comment: So I shouldnt have to do much other then wrap my http request in DataCall in a ASyncTask class.

Comment: I've been using an AsyncTask recently. All you need to do is, as you say, wrap the http request code up into the doInBackground method. if you have defined your class correctly that method will return String (line) which will be one of the paramaters for onPostExecute.

Comment: or you could make the datacall class extend ASyncTask.